# Volume of a solid formed by rotation of area bounded by two functions.

Tags: calculus, integration

So i have two functions:

$y=\frac{x^2}{3}$

and

$x^2+y^2+6x=0$

Now, the first function is convex parabola and the second one can be rewritten as:

$y=\sqrt{-x^2 - 6x}$

From here we can see that this function is positive on her whole domain and it's domain is $[-6,0]$

Now, we have to find the point (or points) where these functions intersect so we could determine the limits of integration.

$y=\frac{x^2}{3}$

$x^2+y^2=6x$

If we put $y$ from the first equation into second equation, we have:

$x^2+\frac{x^4}{9}=6x$

This equation holds for x=0, so that's one point of intersection, now, if we look at the rest of it we have:

$x+\frac{x^3}{9}=6 \Rightarrow x^3 + 9x-54=0$

$x=3$ is one zero of this equation, but that's out of the domain of the second function so it can't be intersection point, but i noticed that if i insert $x=3$ in both equations i get same $y$ and that means that $-3$ is intersection point. How come then that i had $x=-3$ as the solution to this, where did i made a mistake?

Comment: Your second "equation" $x^2+y^2+6x$ is not an equation, it is an expression. Do you mean $x^2+y^2=6x$, your fifth equation, or $x^2+y^2+6x=0$, which would give your third equation, or something else?

Comment: You may be having a problem because you dropped a minus sign when you rearranged the equation.  If your circle _was_ $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ 6x \ = \ 0 \ $ , your final equation should be $ \ x \ ( x^3 \ + \ 9x \ + \ 54) \ = \ 0 \ $ , which factors further as $ \ x \ ( x + 3) \ ( x^2 \ -  \ 3 \ x \ + \ 18 ) \ = \ 0 \ $ , this last factor being an irreducible quadratic (over real numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Your answer did not give which axis to rotate about, so I will assume that is under control. You went wrong on the last step where you divided by x. This will change the function and you will lose zeroes or get extraneous solutions. I suggest graphing the function to see a visual of the difference. The second zero of the function is in fact x = -3.

Comment: Actually, i stated that one zero of that function is $x=0$ and i also stated that $x=0$ is the $x$-coordinate of one of the intersection points, however, i made a mistake in calculations as someone mentioned in the comments section, and after i corrected that mistake i got correct solution, anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Silly me. Glad to help. Also do you have access to a graphing calculator? That could resolve other related issues if you run across them.

Comment: If the graphing calculator is app that creates graphics of functions (i believe it is, but i never used it before so i don't know if that's correct term/name) then i found few online, and i think that it can be helpful in examples like this).